# Listen to write when piping read stream to write stream?

Tags: node.js

I have the code:

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(readFilename, {
    highWaterMark: 10 * 1024
});

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(writeFilename, {
    highWaterMark: 1 * 1024
});

readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

As you can see, the buffer (highWaterMark) size is different for both. The read has a higher buffer, when read pipes to write it is indeed too much for the write buffer to handle. It reserves 9 * 1014 in memory and after it has handled the entire load it calls drain. This is fine.

However. When writing to write manually via `writable.write`, `false` is returned so you may alter the read stream to have a lower buffer (if that's what you wish).

My question is, since I'm piping directly, is there anyway to listen to the write event on the writable? The only thing that I can seem to listen to is the drain event *after* it has already taken in too much.

Answer (score 3):

The general answer is *"no, because there's no need to"*, but the less military one would be *"kinda, but in another way and with consequences"*.

First there's a misunderstanding to what the `drain` event means in a piped stream:

- You're making assumption that it's called when the `Writable` buffer is depleted but that's only node.js internal buffer, not the actual pipe to the filesystem.
- Additionally you're not the only one who's reading that - the `pipe` method actually creates a lot of listeners and `pause`/`resume` logic around both streams.
- So what's actually happening is that the `Readable` is listening on `Writable#drain` event to push some more data into the buffer.

Second, as said - `Writable` does not implement any confirmations that the specific `chunk` has been written, that's simply because on `string` and `Buffer` chunks it would be very hard to tell when those are actually written (even impossible at some point in a simple case of `gzip` stream when a part of a chunk may be written to actual disk).

There is a way to get close enough though (get nearly precise confirmation per chunk):

```
const {PassThrough} = require("stream");

fs.createReadStream(readFilename, {
    highWaterMark: 10 * 1024
})
/* we pipe the readable to a buffer in a passthrough stream */
.pipe(new PassThrough({
    highWaterMark: 1024
}))
/* pipe returns the stream we piped to */
/* now we pipe again, but to a stream with no highWaterMark */
.pipe(
    new PassThrough({
        highWaterMark: 1
    })
    .on("data", () => { 
        /* here's your confirmation called just before this chunk is written and after the last one has started to be written */ 
    })
)
/* and there we push to the write stream */
.pipe(
    fs.createWriteStream(writeFilename, {
        highWaterMark: 1
    })
);
```

Sure, that will definitely come with a performance impact and I don't know how big but it will keep the reading side more or less efficient and writable will get the buffer it needs - but with some extra CPU and perhaps some micro latency for every chunk.

It's up to you to test.

[See more on streams, especially PassThrough here.](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough)

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is. You can listen to the `data` event:

```
readStream.on('data', data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: That's not true - [Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) stream does not emit the data events.